# hide "Recently Recovered Services" from "Current Incidents" dashboard in Icingaweb2

Tags: icinga2

All we want to see is critical issues and warnings in the default dashboard. We don't care about seeing recently recovered anything. Do I need to install Dashing for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm so lazy. You just click the upside down chevron thing to the right of "Muted" and choose settings. Then you click the garbage can icon to the right of whichever dashlet you want to remove.